# Receiving strange values to kafka topic from kura

Tags: json, apache-kafka, mqtt, kura, confluent-control-center

Trying to send data to kafka topic from kura through Mqtt proxy but receiving strange values in kafka topic

[image: attached the screenshot of received values in kafka topic]

we are trying to send json data to kafka topic

Answer (score 1):

The MQTT proxy only sends binary data (bytes or strings), and Control Center can only show strings.

You will want to verify the Kafka producer settings to see if it is truly sending JSON, and not other binary format, or compressed/encrypted bytes.

You can further debug with `kafka-console-consumer`, rather than use any UI tool